# PostgreSQL concatting multiple cases gives null as result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL. The next query works in Oracle but won't work in PSQL:

```
select case 1 when null then null else 1||' ' end ||
       case 2 when null then null else 2||' ' end ||
       case 3 when null then null else 3 end as total
from   numbers
```

If 1 and 2 are not null but only 3 is null, the result of total will be null despite the fact that 1 en 2 are not null and the result of total should not be null.

The end result should be that when one of 3 columns is not null, total should not be null. Is that possible?

Comment: `case 1 when ..` does not make any sense. `1` is never `null`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Postgres - unlike Oracle - an empty string `''` and `null` are two different things. In Oracle a string concatenation with null treats the `null` value as an empty string. However when you store an empty string (`''`) in Oracle it treats it as a `null` value.

In SQL, all (or nearly all) operators are defined such that if any argument is `null` the result is also `null`, e.g. `42 + null` or `'foo'||null`.

Also `case 1 when null` makes no sense. `1` is never `null` and thus the `when` part would never be executed. Additionally you can't test for `null` that way. You need to use `is null` but then you can't use the abbreviated `case` syntax.

You probably meant to write something like this:

```
select case when first_column is null then '' else first_column||' ' end ||
       case when second_column is null then '' else second_column||' ' end ||
       case when third_column is null null then '' else third_column end as total
from   numbers
```

However you can make this a lot easier using `coalesce()`:

```
select coalesce(first_column, '')||' '||coalesce(second_column, '')||' '||coalesce(third_column, '')
```

or use concat() which treats `null` as an empty string:

```
select concat(first_column, ' ', second_column, ' ', third_column)
```

or even simpler use `concat_ws()` "concat with separator":

```
select concat_ws(' ', first_column, second_column, third_column)
```

`concat_ws()` will put the separator (the first parameter) between every value of the other parameters, but treats `null` values and empty strings properly, so that the separator does not occur twice between two values.

`concat('one', ' ', null, ' ', '')` returns `'one  '` 
but `concat_ws(' ', 'one', null, '')` will return `'one'`

Comment: With the final example if I change the separator to #, for visibility, and run the above example on Postgres 12.6:  `concat_ws('#', 'one', null, '')` it returns a string of "one#" not "one". I can get "one" if I use NULLIF('','') around the last parameter: `concat_ws(' ', 'one', null, NULLIF('',''))`